# Objective-c make phone call in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to solve the following problem in objective-c:

1. Application in background
2. For an event, i need to call a specific phone number on the iPhone while it is still in background

As i see my logs, the phone call method will be called, but the phone number not dialing by the iOS.

Here is the action method:

//------------------------------------------------//

```
- (IBAction)actionCall:(id)sender
{  
  id<ICallModel> _AutoCall = [self retrieveAutoCall];

  if(_AutoCall != nil)
  {
    DDLogDebug(@"RESCUE CALL: %@",_AutoCall.PhoneNumber);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",_AutoCall.PhoneNumber]]];
  }

  [self actionCancel:nil];

}
```

//------------------------------------------------//

If the application is active, then it works perfectly.
I've added the proper background modes too.

Is it possible some way to achieve this flow?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I noticed also it works when the app is active, before locking the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow you to start calls if your app is running in the background.

What you could do is using [Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1) to make the user returning to your app.
Once your app is back in the foreground it could start the call.

Comment: Hi There,

Do the user need to tap this local notification to

Comment: @Tom, exactly, the user would tap the notification, which will open your app. Then your app could imidiately start the call.